# Navbar button not working on small devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

so basically when I try to open my website on a small device, I have the bootstrap navbar set to collapse but the button does not work. I would highly appreciate some help. Everything else is working but this is the one thing I can't get to work. I've tried everything I could think of.

HTML

```
      <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Impressions</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link py-1 d-none d-md-inline-block active" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link py-1 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#skills">Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link py-1 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link py-1 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


    
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script src="index.js"charset="UTF-8"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: is your issue that the button is not being clicked? or its being clicked but nothing is being displayed on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is probably due to `d-none` class which is an abreviation for `display: none;`.
Change it to `display: flex;` for example. You may refer to the documentation of flexbox to get more info.
Best.

Answer (score 0):

Your menu items are not showing due to the `d-none` class

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Impressions</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
      
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block active" href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block" href="#skills">Skills</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block" href="#projects">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link py-1 d-md-inline-block" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  
  
      
      <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
    <script src="index.js"charset="UTF-8"></script>
  
    </body>
    </html>
```